# Excel for iPad - Fill without dragging

Tags: ipad, ms-office, ipados, cursor

I want to fill a range of cells but without having to drag, because I don‘t want to drag through 11525 columns.

In the below screenshot, you can see the formula I want to fill along with example results. I need to combine the top row with the far left column.

I already tried using Cmd+D/Cmd+R which didn‘t work, although it was listed in the keybinds menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I find if I want to fill a complete column that if I do the following steps:

1. select the whole column by clicking on its letter,
2. entering the text or formula in the formula bar,
3. then pressing ctrl+enter

It fill each cell in the column. Press ctrl first then enter.

However, if I just want A1 to A200, then I select A1 and scroll down, press shift and click A200 then proceed from step 2 above.